# Speeding up the creation of autoregressive terms in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, optimization, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
groupvar1 groupvar2 time value
1         1         1    5
1         1         2    8
1         1         3    9
1         1         4    12
1         1         5    19
1         2         1    5
1         2         2    8
1         2         3    9
```

and I want to create some autoregressive terms *within each `groupvar1` x `groupvar2` combo*, such that I end up with:

```
groupvar1 groupvar2 time value t1 t2 t3
1         1         1    5     5  5  5
1         1         2    8     5  5  5
1         1         3    9     8  5  5
1         1         4    12    9  8  5
1         1         5    19    12 9  8
1         2         1    5     5  5  5
1         2         2    8     5  5  5
1         2         3    9     8  5  5
```

Basically, I am creating three autoregressive terms `t1`, `t2`, `t3` within each group in the `groupby` object. If the result is `NaN`, I backfill from the current value. My code to do this is:

```
for name, group in df.groupby(['groupvar1', 'groupvar2']):
    for i in range(1, 4):
            group.loc[:,'t' + str(i)] = group.sort_values(by=['time'])['value'].shift(i).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill').values
```

The problem is that on large datasets, this is extremely slow. Is there a way to use a built-in Pandas method that might be faster than this? For example, using `.apply` instead?

Comment: Can you be clearer about how you calculate t1, t2, and t3. I see how your code generates the data, but in plain English what does that data represent? I don't understand what you mean by "autoregressive."

Comment: @Alex - basically, t1 would be the `value` at `time` - 1. t2 would be the `value` at `time` - 2 (hence the use of Pandas `.shift()`. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mess around with groupby objects. In the end it looks like your condition is that the groupvar2 cell should be equal to the groupvar2 cell i elements back. This does what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
groupvar1 = pd.Series([1]*8, name='groupvar1')
groupvar2 = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2], name='groupvar2')
time = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3], name='time')
value = pd.Series([5,8,9,12,19,5,8,9], name='value')
df = pd.concat([groupvar1, groupvar2, time, value], axis=1)
data = [df]
for i in range(1,4):
    temp = df.loc[df['groupvar2'] == df['groupvar2'].shift(-i)]['value']
    temp.name = 't' + str(i)
    data.append(temp.reindex_like(df).shift(i))
res = pd.concat(data, axis=1).bfill()
print(res)

   groupvar1  groupvar2  time  value    t1   t2   t3
0          1          1     1      5   5.0  5.0  5.0
1          1          1     2      8   5.0  5.0  5.0
2          1          1     3      9   8.0  5.0  5.0
3          1          1     4     12   9.0  8.0  5.0
4          1          1     5     19  12.0  9.0  8.0
5          1          2     1      5   5.0  5.0  NaN
6          1          2     2      8   5.0  5.0  NaN
7          1          2     3      9   8.0  5.0  NaN
```

Though you should double check the data at the very end because of the way shift works (note that the last column has NaN's at the end).